# Find the probability that a normal random variable lies between two values

Tags: probability

The time required to assemble an electronic component is normally distributed with a mean and standard deviation of 15 minutes and 8 minutes, respectively.
Find the probability that a randomly picked assembly takes between $12$ and $19$ minutes.

I tried doing $(15-12/8)+(19-15/8)=.6480+.6915=1.3395$ but this was the wrong answer.

Comment: Hint: You should use $Z$ scores

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! I think you misunderstood a key aspect of this site. This is more about *helping* you find the right answer then giving you answers to arbitrary problems. For example, if you were to give us what you've tried, where you've looked, what you've read to answer the problem, and describe why you aren't satisfied/doubt what you've come across, I'm sure others would help. Also, choosing a descriptive title that described the content would help. For more, I recommend reading [How to ask a good question?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/9959/9754)

Comment: Thank you for the information! I redid my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(12-15)/8 and (19-15)/8 are z scores; not the probability values, so you cant just add them up. The probability is given by the area under the normal curve enclosed by your limits, 12 and 19 minutes. Once you have the z-scores, use the z-score table to get the area enclosed by the normal curve from -infinity to 12, and -infinity to 19. Subtract the two, and you have the area under the graph from 12 to 19 minutes, which is your probability value.